# html5 - javascript - filereader select new image

Tags: javascript, html, filereader

I have probably an easy thing to fix.. So basically I have a simple button which then uses filereader API to make a thumbinal of that chosen image... however after I choose, I cannot change it, not remove it... how do I remove it from there?

```js
var f = evt.target.files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
var imgW;
var imgH;

reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
return function(e) {
    var lImg = new Image();
        lImg.src = e.target.result;
        lImg.onload = function(){

            imgW=lImg.width;
            imgH=lImg.height;

            // check which logo is being updated
            if ($(selector).hasClass('rclogo')){
                rclogo = 'y';
                rclogoimg = e.target.result; 
                drawLogo(rclogoimg, 'rc', imgW, imgH); //draws img on canvas
            } ... //removed few conditions
            } else {
                console.debug("it doesn't have eligible class");
            }

            // Render thumbnail.
            var thumbHtml = ['<span><img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                            '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/></span>'].join('');
            $(selector).parent().siblings('.previewThumb').html(thumbHtml);
            $(selector).parent().siblings('.previewThumb').removeClass('hidden')
        }
};
})(f);
```

Now as I said, the initial choosing of a file works perfectly, however when they want to change the image, it does not work anymore.

You can test it under 'logos'
Link: http://vetosports.com/designer/index.html

Cheers,
Tom

Comment: Is there a reason you are `join`ing an array instead of just using string concatenation? If you are doing it for performance reasons all recent browsers are optimized well and now do sting concatenation much faster than a `join` would.

Comment: Can you add more code/details to this? Part of the reason why you cannot change the image may be because of the events and functions not being triggered, and there is not enough information to find if it might be happening.